# Use a Blanket policy to serialize enums as strings with snake case

Tags: enums, system.text.json, .net-8.0, native-aot

I'm moving some libraries to .net 8 and I'm trying to use the new JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower for enums (I have a custom converter that I currently use that uses reflection but I want to drop it).
I can serialize an enum to snake case using this JsonSerializerOptions

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower,
};

options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(namingPolicy: JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower));
```

The problem is that according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation?pivots=dotnet-8-0#jsonstringenumconvertert-converter) The non-generic JsonStringEnumConverter type is not supported for AOT. The solution given is using `[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(UseStringEnumConverter = true)]` in the class inheriting from `JsonSerializerContext` but then I lose the naming policy for enums.

Is there a way to use JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower globally for all enums in an AOT friendly way?

Comment: Looks like this may not be implemented, see [API Proposal: Add option to specify JsonNamingPolicy for enum serialization on JsonSourceGenerationOptions #92828](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828).  MSFT suggests a workaround there but it requires knowing all the enum types in advance, there's no way to set a blanket policy.

Comment: thanks @dbc, if you want post your comment as answer to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not implemented as of .NET 8, see [[API Proposal]: Add option to specify JsonNamingPolicy for enum serialization on JsonSourceGenerationOptions #92828](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828).

> Recently there has been added `UseStringEnumConverter` flag to `JsonSourceGenerationOptions`, but there is no way to configure naming policy for these converters. -[ithline](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828#issue-1919744822).
>
> Sounds reasonable. -[eiriktsarpalis](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828#issuecomment-1741390211).

MSFT's Eirik Tsarpalis [suggests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828#issuecomment-1741394886), as a workaround, to define a `JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum>` subtype for your required naming policy and, for each enum, add it to your serialization context, e.g. like so:

```
public class SnakeCaseLowerStringEnumConverter<TEnum>() 
    : JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum>(JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower) 
    where TEnum : struct, Enum;

[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower,
    Converters = new[] { 
        // Add all known enums here
        typeof(SnakeCaseLowerStringEnumConverter<FirstEnum>), 
        typeof(SnakeCaseLowerStringEnumConverter<SecondEnum>),
        //...
        typeof(SnakeCaseLowerStringEnumConverter<LastEnum>)})]
// Add all known enums here also
[JsonSerializable(typeof(FirstEnum)), 
 JsonSerializable(typeof(SecondEnum)),
 //...
 JsonSerializable(typeof(LastEnum))]
// And also add all other root types to be serialized in this context
[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyModel)),] 
public partial class SnakeCaseLowerContext : JsonSerializerContext { }
```

This, however, requires knowing all the enum types in advance.  There's no way to set a blanket policy.