# How to enable JsonStringEnumConverter for all enums in .NET AOT

Tags: c#, enums, system.text.json, .net-8.0, native-aot

It looks like `JsonStringEnumConverter` requires dynamic code and we should switch to `JsonStringEnumConverter<T>` in AOT.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter<MyEnum>))]
public enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar }

[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyEnum))]
public partial class MyJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext { }
```

I have many enums. Is it possible to create a global policy so that each enum is converted into its string representation and we avoid attributes?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you need to annotate every property for JSON source generation.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you cannot. See [Provide trim/AOT-safe mechanism to (de)serialize enums from strings with JSON source-gen #79311](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79311), specifically [this comment from MSFT's Eirik Tsarpalis](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79311#issuecomment-1578762507): *it looks like using the existing JsonStringEnumConverter factory in AOT is not viable since it will make the compiler warn even in cases where the unsafe factory method is not exercised. It seems we need to pivot to a separate converter design...*

Comment: @PoulBak - it does not answer this question, which is specifically about how to use a universal enum-to-string `JsonConverter` when building with NativeAOT where `JsonStringEnumConverter` does not work,

Comment: Does setting [`[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(UseStringEnumConverter = true)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonsourcegenerationoptionsattribute.usestringenumconverter) as shown in [How to use source generation in System.Text.Json: Blanket policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation?pivots=dotnet-8-0#blanket-policy) meet your needs?  It works but does not support naming policies as noted in [open issue #92828](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [How to use source generation in System.Text.Json: Blanket policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation?pivots=dotnet-8-0#blanket-policy), you can apply [`[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(UseStringEnumConverter = true)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonsourcegenerationoptionsattribute.usestringenumconverter) to your serialization contexts to force all enums to be serialized as strings:

> Instead of using the [`JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter-1) type, you can apply a blanket policy to serialize enums as strings by using the [JsonSourceGenerationOptionsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonsourcegenerationoptionsattribute). Create a [JsonSerializerContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonsourcegenerationoptionsattribute) class and annotate it with the [JsonSerializableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializableattribute) *and [JsonSourceGenerationOptionsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonsourcegenerationoptionsattribute)* attributes

Thus you should modify your `MyJsonSerializerContext` as follows:

```
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(UseStringEnumConverter = true)]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyEnum))]
public partial class MyJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext { }
```

The code shown in the question does not use a [naming policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0#use-a-built-in-naming-policy) such as [`JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.camelcase?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-camelcase) for enum serialization.  If you need one, note that, as indicated in [issue #92828](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92828), **as of .NET 8** there does not seem to be a way to configure one with this approach.  I.e. the setting `UseStringEnumConverter = true` lacks feature parity with [`new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonstringenumconverter-ctor(system-text-json-jsonnamingpolicy-system-boolean)).  The workaround suggested by MSFT's Eirik Tsarpalis is to apply the required converters to the serialization context instead of to each enum:

```
public class CamelCaseEnumConverter<TEnum>() : 
    JsonStringEnumConverter<TEnum>(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) where TEnum : struct, Enum;

[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(
    Converters = new[] { 
        // Add all known enums here
        typeof(CamelCaseEnumConverter<MyEnum>)}),
// Add all known enums here also (which you were already doing):
 JsonSerializable(typeof(MyEnum))]
public partial class MyJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext { }
```

For more see: *[Use a Blanket policy to serialize enums as strings with snake case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77575596/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question of avoiding attributes by using a custom `JsonSerializerContext`, but I still have to manually include enums with `JsonSerializable`. I wish we didn't have to do this.